# Getting error as Keys::KEYS must be initailized by constructor

Tags: c++

I'm doing a course **How to create an advanced keylogger from scratch for windows** from Udemy.

Here I'm creating a custom header file **KeyConstants.h** which will map the physical keys to some human readable name but I'm getting some error in this file.

Here I have created a map which will map the value of key pressed by the user to the human readable format.

My code in the file is

```
#ifndef KEY_CONSTANTS_H
#define KEY_CONSTANTS_H

#include <map>
#include <string>

class KeyPair
{

public:
    KeyPair (const std::string &vk = "", const std::string &name = "") : VKName (vk), Name (name) {}

    std::string VKName;
    std::string Name;
};

class Keys
{
public:
    static std::map<int, KeyPair> KEYS;
};

std::map<int, KeyPair> Keys::KEYS = {
    {0xC1, {"[VK_ABNT_C1]", "[Abnt C1]"}},
    {0xC2, {"[VK_ABNT_C2]", "[Abnt C2]"}},
    {0x6B, {"[VK_ADD]", "[Numpad +]"}},
    {0xF6, {"[VK_ATTN]", "[Attn]"}},
    {0x08, {"[VK_BACK]", "[Backspace]"}},
    {0x03, {"[VK_CANCEL]", "[Break]"}},
    {0x0C, {"[VK_CLEAR]", "[Clear]"}},
    {0xF7, {"[VK_CRSEL]", "[Cr Sel]"}},
    {0x6E, {"[VK_DECIMAL]", "[Numpad .]"}},
    {0x6F, {"[VK_DIVIDE]", "[Numpad /]"}},
    {0xF9, {"[VK_EREOF]", "[Er Eof]"}},
    {0x1B, {"[VK_ESCAPE]", "[Esc]"}},
    {0x2B, {"[VK_EXECUTE]", "[Execute]"}},
    {0xF8, {"[VK_EXSEL]", "[Ex Sel]"}},
    {0xE6, {"[VK_ICO_CLEAR]", "[IcoClr]"}},
    {0xE3, {"[VK_ICO_HELP]", "[IcoHlp]"}},
    {0x30, {"[VK_KEY_0]", "[D0]"}},
    {0x31, {"[VK_KEY_1]", "[D1]"}},
    {0x32, {"[VK_KEY_2]", "[D2]"}},
    {0x33, {"[VK_KEY_3]", "[D3]"}},
    {0x34, {"[VK_KEY_4]", "[D4]"}},
    {0x35, {"[VK_KEY_5]", "[D5]"}},
    {0x36, {"[VK_KEY_6]", "[D6]"}},
    {0x37, {"[VK_KEY_7]", "[D7]"}},
    {0x38, {"[VK_KEY_8]", "[D8]"}},
    {0x39, {"[VK_KEY_9]", "[D9]"}},
    {0x41, {"[VK_KEY_A]", "[A]"}},
    {0x42, {"[VK_KEY_B]", "[B]"}},
    {0x43, {"[VK_KEY_C]", "[C]"}},
    {0x44, {"[VK_KEY_D]", "[D]"}},
    {0x45, {"[VK_KEY_E]", "[E]"}},
    {0x46, {"[VK_KEY_F]", "[F]"}},
    {0x47, {"[VK_KEY_G]", "[G]"}},
    {0x48, {"[VK_KEY_H]", "[H]"}},
    {0x49, {"[VK_KEY_I]", "[I]"}},
    {0x4A, {"[VK_KEY_J]", "[J]"}},
    {0x4B, {"[VK_KEY_K]", "[K]"}},
    {0x4C, {"[VK_KEY_L]", "[L]"}},
    {0x4D, {"[VK_KEY_M]", "[M]"}},
    {0x4E, {"[VK_KEY_N]", "[N]"}},
    {0x4F, {"[VK_KEY_O]", "[O]"}},
    {0x50, {"[VK_KEY_P]", "[P]"}},
    {0x51, {"[VK_KEY_Q]", "[Q]"}},
    {0x52, {"[VK_KEY_R]", "[R]"}},
    {0x53, {"[VK_KEY_S]", "[S]"}},
    {0x54, {"[VK_KEY_T]", "[T]"}},
    {0x55, {"[VK_KEY_U]", "[U]"}},
    {0x56, {"[VK_KEY_V]", "[V]"}},
    {0x57, {"[VK_KEY_W]", "[W]"}},
    {0x58, {"[VK_KEY_X]", "[X]"}},
    {0x59, {"[VK_KEY_Y]", "[Y]"}},
    {0x5A, {"[VK_KEY_Z]", "[Z]"}},
    {0x6A, {"[VK_MULTIPLY]", "[Numpad *]"}},
    {0xFC, {"[VK_NONAME]", "[NoName]"}},
    {0x60, {"[VK_NUMPAD0]", "[N0]"}},
    {0x61, {"[VK_NUMPAD1]", "[N1]"}},
    {0x62, {"[VK_NUMPAD2]", "[N2]"}},
    {0x63, {"[VK_NUMPAD3]", "[N3]"}},
    {0x64, {"[VK_NUMPAD4]", "[N4]"}},
    {0x65, {"[VK_NUMPAD5]", "[N5]"}},
    {0x66, {"[VK_NUMPAD6]", "[N6]"}},
    {0x67, {"[VK_NUMPAD7]", "[N7]"}},
    {0x68, {"[VK_NUMPAD8]", "[N8]"}},
    {0x69, {"[VK_NUMPAD9]", "[N9]"}},
    {0xBA, {"[VK_OEM_1]", "[OEM_1 (: ;)]"}},
    {0xE2, {"[VK_OEM_102]", "[OEM_102 (> <)]"}},
    {0xBF, {"[VK_OEM_2]", "[OEM_2 (? /)]"}},
    {0xC0, {"[VK_OEM_3]", "[OEM_3 (~ `)]"}},
    {0xDB, {"[VK_OEM_4]", "[OEM_4 ({ [)]"}},
    {0xDC, {"[VK_OEM_5]", "[OEM_5 (| \\)]"}},
    {0xDD, {"[VK_OEM_6]", "[OEM_6 (} ])]"}},
    {0xDE, {"[VK_OEM_7]", "[OEM_7 (\" \')]"}},
    {0xDF, {"[VK_OEM_8]", "[OEM_8 (: !)]"}},
    {0xF0, {"[VK_OEM_ATTN]", "[Oem Attn]"}},
    {0xF3, {"[VK_OEM_AUTO]", "[AUTO]"}},
    {0xE1, {"[VK_OEM_AX]", "[Ax]"}},
    {0xF5, {"[VK_OEM_BACKTAB]", "[Back Tab]"}},
    {0xFE, {"[VK_OEM_CLEAR]", "[OemClr]"}},
    {0xBC, {"[VK_OEM_COMMA]", "[OEM_COMMA (< ,)]"}},
    {0xF2, {"[VK_OEM_COPY]", "[Copy]"}},
    {0xEF, {"[VK_OEM_CUSEL]", "[Cu Sel]"}},
    {0xF4, {"[VK_OEM_ENLW]", "[Enlw]"}},
    {0xF1, {"[VK_OEM_FINISH]", "[Finish]"}},
    {0x95, {"[VK_OEM_FJ_LOYA]", "[Loya]"}},
    {0x93, {"[VK_OEM_FJ_MASSHOU]", "[Mashu]"}},
    {0x96, {"[VK_OEM_FJ_ROYA]", "[Roya]"}},
    {0x94, {"[VK_OEM_FJ_TOUROKU]", "[Touroku]"}},
    {0xEA, {"[VK_OEM_JUMP]", "[Jump]"}},
    {0xBD, {"[VK_OEM_MINUS]", "[OEM_MINUS (_ -)]"}},
    {0xEB, {"[VK_OEM_PA1]", "[OemPa1]"}},
    {0xEC, {"[VK_OEM_PA2]", "[OemPa2]"}},
    {0xED, {"[VK_OEM_PA3]", "[OemPa3]"}},
    {0xBE, {"[VK_OEM_PERIOD]", "[OEM_PERIOD (> .)]"}},
    {0xBB, {"[VK_OEM_PLUS]", "[OEM_PLUS (+ =)]"}},
    {0xE9, {"[VK_OEM_RESET]", "[Reset]"}},
    {0xEE, {"[VK_OEM_WSCTRL]", "WsCtrl]"}},
    {0xFD, {"[VK_PA1]", "[Pa1]"}},
    {0xE7, {"[VK_PACKET]", "[Packet]"}},
    {0xFA, {"[VK_PLAY]", "[Play]"}},
    {0xE5, {"[VK_PROCESSKEY]", "[Process]"}},
    {0x0D, {"[VK_RETURN]", "[Enter]"}},
    {0x29, {"[VK_SELECT]", "[Select]"}},
    {0x6C, {"[VK_SEPARATOR]", "[Separator]"}},
    {0x20, {"[VK_SPACE]", "[Space]"}},
    {0x6D, {"[VK_SUBTRACT]", "[Num -]"}},
    {0x09, {"[VK_TAB]", "[Tab]"}},
    {0xFB, {"[VK_ZOOM]", "[Zoom]"}},
    {0x1E, {"[VK_ACCEPT]", "[Accept]"}},
    {0x5D, {"[VK_APPS]", "[Context Menu]"}},
    {0xA6, {"[VK_BROWSER_BACK]", "[Browser Back]"}},
    {0xAB, {"[VK_BROWSER_FAVORITES]", "[Browser Favorites]"}},
    {0xA7, {"[VK_BROWSER_FORWARD]", "[Browser Forward]"}},
    {0xAC, {"[VK_BROWSER_HOME]", "[Browser Home]"}},
    {0xA8, {"[VK_REFRESH]", "[Browser Refresh]"}},
    {0xAA, {"[VK_SEARCH]", "[Browser Search]"}},
    {0xA9, {"[VK_STOP]", "[Browser Stop]"}},
    {0x14, {"[VK_CAPITAL]", "[Caps Lock]"}},
    {0x1C, {"[VK_CONVERT]", "[Convert]"}},
    {0x2E, {"[VK_DELETE]", "[Delete]"}},
    {0x28, {"[VK_DOWN]", "[Arrow Down]"}},
    {0x23, {"[VK_END]", "[End]"}},
    {0x70, {"[VK_F1]", "[F1]"}},
    {0x79, {"[VK_F10]", "[F10]"}},
    {0x7A, {"[VK_F11]", "[F11]"}},
    {0x7B, {"[VK_F12]", "[F12]"}},
    {0x7C, {"[VK_F13]", "[F13]"}},
    {0x7D, {"[VK_F14]", "[F14]"}},
    {0x7E, {"[VK_F15]", "[F15]"}},
    {0x7F, {"[VK_F16]", "[F16]"}},
    {0x80, {"[VK_F17]", "[F17]"}},
    {0x81, {"[VK_F18]", "[F18]"}},
    {0x82, {"[VK_F19]", "[F19]"}},
    {0x71, {"[VK_F2]", "[F2]"}},
    {0x83, {"[VK_F20]", "[F20]"}},
    {0x84, {"[VK_F21]", "[F21]"}},
    {0x85, {"[VK_F22]", "[F22]"}},
    {0x86, {"[VK_F23]", "[F23]"}},
    {0x87, {"[VK_F24]", "[F24]"}},
    {0x72, {"[VK_F3]", "[F3]"}},
    {0x73, {"[VK_F4]", "[F4]"}},
    {0x74, {"[VK_F5]", "[F5]"}},
    {0x75, {"[VK_F6]", "[F6]"}},
    {0x76, {"[VK_F7]", "[F7]"}},
    {0x77, {"[VK_F8]", "[F8]"}},
    {0x78, {"[VK_F9]", "[F9]"}},
    {0x18, {"[VK_FINAL]", "[Final]"}},
    {0x2F, {"[VK_HELP]", "[Help]"}},
    {0x24, {"[VK_HOME]", "[Home]"}},
    {0xE4, {"[VK_ICO_00]", "[Ico00]"}},
    {0x2D, {"[VK_INSERT]", "[Insert]"}},
    {0x17, {"[VK_JUNJA]", "[Junja]"}},
    {0x15, {"[VK_KANA]", "[Kana]"}},
    {0x19, {"[VK_KANJI]", "[Kanji]"}},
    {0xB6, {"[VK_LAUNCH_APP1]", "[App1]"}},
    {0xB7, {"[VK_LAUNCH_APP2]", "[App2]"}},
    {0xB4, {"[VK_LAUNCH_MAIL]", "[Mail]"}},
    {0xB5, {"[VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT]", "[Media]"}},
    {0x01, {"[VK_LBUTTON]", "[Left Button]"}},
    {0xA2, {"[VK_LCONTROL]", "[Left Ctrl]"}},
    {0x25, {"[VK_LEFT]", "[Arrow Left]"}},
    {0xA4, {"[VK_LMENU]", "[Left Alt]"}},
    {0xA0, {"[VK_LSHIFT]", "[Left Shift]"}},
    {0x5B, {"[VK_LWIN]", "[Left Win]"}},
    {0x04, {"[VK_MBUTTON]", "[Middle Button]"}},
    {0xB0, {"[VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK]", "[Next Track]"}},
    {0xB3, {"[VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE]", "[Play / Pause]"}},
    {0xB1, {"[VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK]", "[Previous Track]"}},
    {0xB2, {"[VK_MEDIA_STOP]", "[Stop]"}},
    {0x1F, {"[VK_MODECHANGE]", "[Mode Change]"}},
    {0x22, {"[VK_NEXT]", "[Page Down]"}},
    {0x1D, {"[VK_NONCONVERT]", "[Non Convert]"}},
    {0x90, {"[VK_NUMLOCK]", "[Num Lock]"}},
    {0x92, {"[VK_OEM_FJ_JISHO]", "[Jisho]"}},
    {0x13, {"[VK_PAUSE]", "[Pause]"}},
    {0x2A, {"[VK_PRINT]", "[Print]"}},
    {0x21, {"[VK_PRIOR]", "[Page Up]"}},
    {0x02, {"[VK_RBUTTON]", "[Right Button]"}},
    {0xA3, {"[VK_RCONTROL]", "[Right Ctrl]"}},
    {0x27, {"[VK_RIGHT]", "[Arrow Right]"}},
    {0xA5, {"[VK_RMENU]", "[Right Alt]"}},
    {0xA1, {"[VK_RSHIFT]", "[Right Shift]"}},
    {0x5C, {"[VK_RWIN]", "[Right Win]"}},
    {0x91, {"[VK_SCROLL]", "[Scroll Lock]"}},
    {0x5F, {"[VK_SLEEP]", "[Sleep]"}},
    {0x2C, {"[VK_SNAPSHOT]", "[Print Screen]"}},
    {0x26, {"[VK_UP]", "[Arrow Up]"}},
    {0xAE, {"[VK_VOLUME_DOWN]", "[Volume Down]"}},
    {0xAD, {"[VK_VOLUME_MUTE]", "[Volume Mute]"}},
    {0xAF, {"[VK_VOLUME_UP]", "[Volume Up]"}},
    {0x05, {"[VK_XBUTTON1]", "[X Button 1]"}},
    {0x06, {"[VK_XBUTTON2]", "[X Button 2]"}},
};

#endif // KEY_CONSTANTS_H
```

Comment: What's the compiler and version? Does it support C++11? BTW you should put the definition of `Keys::KEYS` in the implementation file.

Comment: I'm using CodeBlock 16.01

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, did you compile with C++11 (or later) mode? Your code should be valid with C++11. [LIVE](http://rextester.com/EBJER45737)

Comment: Off-topic:  Differentiating variable and type names by case only is poor coding (guideline) practice.  Try naming differently, e.g. appending "_t" to the type name.

Comment: Placing variables in header files and their data is poor programming practice.  Every file that includes your include file will get a copy of that data and the compiler will have to parse all those statements each time.  Move the variable to a source file.

Comment: I'm following the tutorial from Udemy. Using it,  I'm creating one source file and remaining 7 header file and each header file will perform different task.  So,  should I write the whole code in single file? @Thomas Matthews

Comment: A good rule of thumb for coding is one class or structure per header file and the implementation in a source file.  Static variables should be initialized in the source file.  You should modify your build tools to allow multiple files.

Comment: Thanks! Will do the same @ThomasMatthews

Comment: I have enable the flag of c++11 but now it's giving me an error saying
unrecognized commmand line option "-std=c++11"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

Compilation directory was set to dev-cpp. Just installed tdm-gcc and changed the compilation directory to tdm-gcc and now it's working fine.